# What version of Qt is supposed to be in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, qt

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10. In distrowatch the version of Qt is 4.7.4. In installation is 4.7.4 too. But I think it's not the real Qt 4.7.4! Because there is no Persian translation in `/usr/share/qt4/translation`. In archlinux everything is ok but in Ubuntu Qt looks to be 4.7.3 :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not incorrect. It is in fact **4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8**. The source package is qt4-x11 and the corresponding [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/qt4-x11) lists the version number.

What you are missing is the *translation file* for a specific language. The language files are from the **libqtcore4** package. Just to make sure Ubuntu did not drop a language by mistake, we can try looking at the Debian version of this package. For comparison:

- The [list of files](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libqtcore4/filelist) in the Debian libqtcore4 package. (18 files)
- The [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/libqtcore4/filelist) in the Ubuntu libqtcore4 package. (19 files)

Additionally the source code contains a [translations directory](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/qt4-x11/oneiric/files/head:/translations/), where the language files are located. There is an interesting statement in the README file:

> The French, German, and Simplified Chinese translation files are
>   supported by Qt. All other translations are contributed by third
>   parties. These are provided without guarantees and may disappear from
>   future Qt releases.

If any translation files are missing from package, they might not be officially supported.

(I've checked the [Arch Linux version](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/qt/files/) of the package. There are indeed  more translation files: 30. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. My bet is to „borrow” the ones you need.)

Comment: So do I have to include translation file within my package? I'm going to put translation file in /usr/share/qt4/translation. But think my package should not change contents of that directory...

Comment: I'd suggest to put the translation file in `/usr/share/qt4/translation`. I don't think it will introduce any conflicts, since the original package does not contain this language. (And considering the different package versions, that is the place for such files.) If you had a Persian language pack for QT4, that would install the translation file to the same location. (But as always: make sure to backup the directory before making any changes.)